# Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3' in kubernetes

Tags: java, amazon-s3, apache-flink, flink-streaming

ERROR: Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugins: flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/plugins.html for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme, please add the scheme to the configuration fs.allowed-fallback-filesystems. For a full list of supported file systems, please see https://nightlies.apache.org/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/filesystems/.

when i am trying to deploy the flink in kubernetes had been getting error... followed the documentation that is copy the s3-fs-hadoop jar files into the plugins folder with folder name s3-fs-hadoop (also tried with presto) and tried with s3:// and s3a:// also but always getting the same error. i copied the jar files while creating the docker image .

```
FROM flink:1.15.4-scala_2.12-java11

RUN mkdir /flink-jar

RUN mkdir /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop

RUN mkdir /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto

COPY ./s3-fs-hadoop/flink-s3-fs-hadoop-1.15.4.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-hadoop

COPY ./s3-fs-hadoop/flink-s3-fs-presto-1.15.4.jar /opt/flink/plugins/s3-fs-presto

COPY ./target/kafka-s3-connect-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar /flink-jar/app.jar

RUN chmod -R a+w /flink-jar
```

just for test i wrote both flink-s3-fs-presto and flink-s3-fs-hadoop

Comment: And what's the error?

Comment: @tquadrat Could not find a file system implementation for scheme 's3'. The scheme is directly supported by Flink through the following plugins: flink-s3-fs-hadoop, flink-s3-fs-presto. Please ensure that each plugin resides within its own subfolder within the plugins directory. See https://ci.apache.org/projects/flink/flink-docs-stable/ops/plugins.html for more information. If you want to use a Hadoop file system for that scheme,